# qtip will not disappear when i will click the another qtip

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I used the qtip2 jquery plugin. The first qtip will appear when i will click the menu.the second qtip will appear when the mouse enter the first qtip. I set the first qtip is disappear when i will click the outside of the first qtip.But first qtip will not disappear when i will click the second qtip.

first Qtip:

```
  hide = {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 300,
    }
```

Actual result:first qtip is disappear when i will click the outside of the first qtip and click the second qtip itself.

Expected Result:first qtip will disappear when i will click the outside of the first qtip. but first qtip will not disappear when i will click the second qtip.

Note:The second qtip is fully placed the outside of the first qtip.

my code is:

```
 _this.qtip({
                style: {
                    classes: 'Details',
                    tip: {
                        corner: 'right center'
                    }
                },
                content:{
                    text:"HAI"
                },
                show: {
                    ready: true
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    when: 'unfocus',
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'right center',
                    at: 'center left',
                    adjust: {
                        x: -8,
                        y: 0
                    }
                },
              events: {
                render: function(event, api){
                    $(this, api.elements.content).on("click", function(){
                        $('.tip-studio-right-menu').qtip("show");
                    });
                },
                hide: function(event, api){
                    api.destroy();
                }
             }
});
```

Comment: html please to understand the structure

Comment: What you had tried so far?

Comment: I tried to show the first qtip when i will click the second qtip.
$(this).on("click", function(){
               $(this).find('.firstQtip').qtip("show");
              })

Comment: Could you please post the Qtip code and your html code here so we could identify your issue. Since you've only posted part of your qtip init code, it's very hard to solve the issue.

Comment: i post the full code